# How can I group labels in a Prometheus query?

Tags: prometheus, promql

If I have a metric with the following labels:

```
my_metric{group="group a"}  100
my_metric{group="group b"}  100
my_metric{group="group c"}  100
my_metric{group="misc group a"}  1
my_metric{group="misc group b"}  2
my_metric{group="misc group c"}  1
my_metric{group="misc group d"}  1
```

Is it possible to do a query or even a `label_replace` that combines the 'misc' groups together?

(I realize that the metric cardinality needs to be improved, and I've updated the app to fix it. However it left me with this question for if I wanted to fix the metrics via a query later)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, you can you use label replace to group all the misc together:

```
sum by (new_group) (
  label_replace(
    label_replace(my_metric, "new_group", "$1", "group", ".+"),
    "new_group", "misc", "group", "misc group.+"
  )
)
```

The inner label_replace copies all values from group into new_group, the outer overwrites those which match "misc group.+" with "misc", and we then sum by the "new_group" label.  The reason for using a new label is the series would no longer be unique if we just overwrote the "group" label, and the sum wouldn't work.

Comment: Isn't it possible to archieve the same result by only doing:

`sum by (misc) (
  label_replace(my_metrics, "misc", "group", "misc group.+")
)`

Comment: For grouping the labels based on regex, refer to the accepted answer from this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66669688/group-labels-in-a-prometheus-query-based-on-regex

Answer (score 64):

It's even easier

```
sum by (group) (my_metric)
```

Comment: Does this solve the second part of the original question of grouping the 'misc' labels?

Comment: You  can also combine them if you require like `sum(my_metric{group=~"group.*"}) by (group)`

Comment: For this query, if I write an alert like `sum by (group) (my_metric) > 0`, how can I access the `group` name? Something like `{{group}}`?

Answer (score 16):

You can use a regex query:

```
my_metric{group=~"misc group.+"}
```

That will give you everything where `group` starts with "misc group".

Comment: This will match all that is misc group.* but not group by.  (e.g. all independent metrics that match the regex above will show as a separate metric not all as one metric)