# Prometheus group by substring of label

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to solve a problem of making a sum and group by query in Prometheus on a metric where the labels assigned to the metric values to unique to my sum and group by requirements.

I have a metric sampling sizes of ElasticSearch indices, where the index names are labelled on the metric. The indices are named like this and are placed in the label "index":

`project.<projectname>.<uniqueid>.<date>`

with concrete value that would look like this:

`project.sample-x.ad19f880-2f16-11e7-8a64-jkzdfaskdfjk.2018.03.12`

`project.sample-y.jkcjdjdk-1234-11e7-kdjd-005056bf2fbf.2018.03.12`

`project.sample-x.ueruwuhd-dsfg-11e7-8a64-kdfjkjdjdjkk.2018.03.11`

`project.sample-y.jksdjkfs-2f16-11e7-3454-005056bf2fbf.2018.03.11`

so if I had the short version of values in the "index" label I would just do:

`sum(metric) by (index)`

but what I am trying to do is something like this:

`sum(metric) by ("project.<projectname>")`

where I can group by a substring of the "index" label. How can this be done with a Prometheus query? I assume this could maybe be solved using a label_replace as part of the group, but I can't just see how to "truncate" the label value to achieve this.

Best regards

Lars Milland

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45163502/1062129 for a possible way to do this with `label_replace`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it'd be best to fix the metrics, the next best thing is to use `metric_relabel_configs` using the same technique as [this blog post](https://www.robustperception.io/extracting-labels-from-legacy-metric-names/):

```
  metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [index]
    regex: 'project\.([^.]*)\..*'
    replacement: '${1}'
    target_label: project
```

You will then have a `project` label that you can use as usual.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to use [label_replace()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function in order to extract the needed parts of the label into a separate label and then group by this label when summing the results. For example, the following query extracts the `project.sample-y` from `project.sample-y.jksdjkfs-2f16-11e7-3454-005056bf2fbf.2018.03.11` value stored in the `index` label and puts  the extracted value into `project_name` label. Then the `sum()` is grouped by `project_name` label values:

```
sum(
  label_replace(metric, "project_name", "$1", "index", "(project[.][^.]+).+")
) by (project_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the `index` label naming convention is wrong. These constituents should clearly be *separate metric labels* instead. So, instead of `project.<projectname>.<uniqueid>.<date>` you should be storing timeseries with labels as in:

`project{projectname="xxx", uniqueid="yyy"}`

As for the `date` part, I assume this already covered by the sample timestamps themselves? There are plenty of functions like `timestamp()`, `month()`, `day()` etc to manipulate the timestamp.

So you have two options:

- fix the metrics exporter to separate the *labels* instead of concatenating this information into the metric name itself,
- OR, if you can't alter the exporter, use *metric relabeling* to convert the `index` label into new time series with the label set I described above. You can then use standard Prometheus functions as you described. See [this article](https://www.robustperception.io/extracting-full-labels-from-consul-tags/) for an example of how you could do this.

Comment: I am not in control of the metric exporter, and would also not like to do this in a relabeling exercise when scraping the metrics by Prometheus. I am looking for a solution with Prometheus query. But as question is stated, I simply can't figure out how to drop parts of the "index" label so I can group by only the first parts and not the whole full label value. So if anyone know how to trim/truncate the label as part of a query, and then use the trimmed value in a group please advice.

Comment: try using the `__name__` hidden label. Something in the likes of:

`sum({_name__=~"project.[a|b|c}*"})`

Comment: Maybe I am explaining my problem wrong. It is not the name of the metric that I want to truncate parts of and group by. It is a label on the metric.

Comment: So what I thought would work is something like:


sum(metric) by (label_replace(....))

I just don't know how to use the label_replace function inside the grouping part and truncate the the "index" label using some smart regular expression.