# Prometheus | How can I group a label whose label values change in a certain pattern?

Tags: prometheus

I have a metric which has an *instance* label whose value pattern like this:

cga-ops01.it.local:1000
cue-ops01.it.local:1000
cga-ops02.it.local:1000
cue-ops02.it.local:1000
cue-ops03.it.local:1000

The only part I care about is first part of the string before first `-` char, and I want to group by this label to two groups with `sum by` PromQL command:

- cga
- cue

Edit:

I created query:

```
sum by(infra) (
    label_replace(
        rate(wallet_operation_total[1m]), "infra", "cue", "instance", "cue-.*"
    )
)
or
sum by(infra) (
    label_replace(
        rate(wallet_operation_total[1m]), "infra", "cga", "instance", "cga-.*"
    )
)
```

The outcome is almost what the outcome of what I'm looking for, but there is a label value named "Value" and I don't know where it's coming from. 
[image]

Comment: You can add either a temporary label (https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) or a permanent one (https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/). Then aggregate as usual.

Comment: Also, you can simply run two queries: one with `{instance=~"cue-.+"}` and another one with `{instance=~"cga-.+"}`.

Comment: @anemyte Can you provide a concrete example as an answer?

Comment: There are examples in similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334224/prometheus-group-by-substring-of-label?rq=1) and in the docs which I mentioned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus group by substring of label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334224/prometheus-group-by-substring-of-label)

Comment: I already looked at these SO questions before creating mine. I edited the question with the point what I've reached.

Comment: Note that you can simplify your expression with `sum by(infra) (label_replace(rate(wallet_operation_total[1m]), "infra", "$1", "instance", "([^-]*)-.*"))`. This `Value` thing looks like a grafana issue. You can inspect objects returned by grafana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
sum by(infra) (
    label_replace(
        rate(wallet_operation_total[1m]), "infra", "$1", "instance", "([^-]+).+"
    )
)
```

The inner [label_replace](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) extracts a prefix until the first `-` char from the `instance` label and stores it into the `infra` label. The outer `sum(...) by (infra)` sums the metrics by the `infra` label.