# Group labels in a Prometheus query based on regex

Tags: prometheus, promql

Imagine I have metrics like this:

```
sample_metric{type="some-type1-1234"} 2
sample_metric{type="some-type1-5678"} 1
sample_metric{type="some-type2-9876"} 4
sample_metric{type="some-type2-4321"} 3
```

Now I would like to sum the metric values based on types that follow the same **pattern**. So, for the above example the desired result would be to have 2 sums:

```
type1: 3
type2: 7
```

This question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154993/how-can-i-group-labels-in-a-prometheus-query), however in my case I don't know the groups in advance. I just know the pattern that they follow. Is there a way to achieve this with one query using regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, again with the help of [the accepted answer from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45163502/8344799). Posting the answer for those who will have come across the same problem in the future:

```
sum by (type_group) (
  label_replace(
    label_replace(sample_metric, "type_group", "$1", "type", ".+"),
    "type_group", "$1", "type", "some-(\\w+(-\\w+)*)-.*"
  )
)
```

So, the inner `label_replace` introduces a new label called `type_group`, whereas the outer `label_replace` replaces the values with the `type` pulled from the original label, with the help of regex. So, `type_group` will contain values, such as `type1` and `type2` (`$1` refers to the regex group to pull). The inner group `(-\\w+)*` indicates that your group might be comprised of several parts, e.g. `type1-type12`, and it will treat it as yet another group.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use two [label_replace()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) functions - a single `label_replace()` would be enough:

```
sum by (type_group) (
  label_replace(
    sample_metric,
    "type_group", "$1", "type", "some-(\\w+(-\\w+)*)-.*"
  )
)
```

It matches the `type` label with the given regexp - `some-(\w+(-\w+)*)-.*` - and then puts the matched outer group into `type_group` label. Then `sum by (type_group) (...)` sums results grouped by the constructed `type_group` label.