# How to manage different environment specific alerts in Prometheus

Tags: colors, tabs, prometheus

I have  one Prometheus for all types of environments, i.e. DEV, PROD, STAGING ...
it's  useful to see whole big  picture in one place but  i would like  to have something  like tabs or color mark for  different types of environments

I have different  titles for  different  types of  environments,  i.e.

```
DEV | Hight CPU usage
PROD| Hight CPU usage
```

....
i would like  to have different  tabs or  nested groups something like this:

```
DEV
  |_ DEV | Hight CPU usage
PROD
  |_ PROD| Hight CPU usage
```

Comment: Why not use Grafana https://grafana.com/ ? Or do you want that your prometheus query results in some nested components?

Comment: Does your environments are usung differerent prometheus servers? If so you can use https://thanos.io/ to query different prometheus servers on the same dashboard. Thanos is like a distributed and long storage which can have multiple prometheus instances as source of data.

Comment: 1) I use one Prometheus for all environments...

2) Yes we use Grafana  but  Grafana has different purpose. and all alerts in Grafana != all alerts in Prometheus .

I would like to see  nested groups here <my prometheus  server>:port/alerts
right now I see all alerts  for all environments in the flat list

Comment: AFAIK the result of a promQL is always flat because it is like rows in databases. What you can do is to group by a label like here https://stackoverflow.com/q/45154993/2096986